# python capturing environment variables from proxy

Tags: python, linux, proxy

when i use an external bash script against my proxy i get all the environment varibles

```
#!/bin/bash

CAPTURE_FILE=/var/log/capture_data
env >> ${CAPTURE_FILE}

# we use exit code 1 to ensure this does not effect the actual browsing
exit 1
#
```

output of this script when client accesses a webpage:

```
HTTP_PORT=80
HTTP_HOST=ads.cnn.com
SERVER[adserver]=ad3ad3:9678:1
CLIENT[referer]=http://edition.cnn.com/
HTTP_PROTO=http
CLIENT[host]=ads.cnn.com
SERVER[vary]=Cookie
SERVER[connection]=Keep-Alive
CLIENTID=2
USERNAME=anonymous@192.168.221.1
SERVER[keep-alive]=timeout=5, max=15
SERVER[date]=Thu, 02 Feb 2012 12:09:46 GMT
SERVER[content-type]=text/html
CLIENT[user-agent]=Safari
PWD=/
VERSION=SR.4.2.2.MR.20110523
```

Now, i used **os.environ** for python (thanks for one of the previous posts here) and it works but only from the terminal and not when proxy passes all requests to it

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

def capture():

    log = os.environ
    data = open("/tmp/capture.log", "a")
    for key in log.keys():
        data.write((key))
        data.write(" : ")
        for n in log[key]:
            data.write('%s' % ((n)))
        data.write("\n")
    data.close()
    sys.exit(1)

def main():

    capture()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

i can read data from the standard sys.stdin.readlines() but i get more precise results from the environment variables when proxy redirects requests to the script...

any ideas why the python script does not display any data?

log from /var/log/messages

```
Feb  3 22:29:02 safesquid capture.py: abrt: detected unhandled Python exception in /opt/safesquid/safesquid/scripts/capture.py
Feb  3 22:30:00 safesquid capture.py: abrt: detected unhandled Python exception in /opt/safesquid/safesquid/scripts/capture.py
Feb  3 22:30:00 safesquid capture.py: abrt: detected unhandled Python exception in /opt/safesquid/safesquid/scripts/capture.py
Feb  3 22:30:01 safesquid capture.py: abrt: detected unhandled Python exception in /opt/safesquid/safesquid/scripts/capture.py
```

**RESOLVED:**

i ported this same script to centos 6.2 and it worked....seems it had issues on fedora.

Comment: Huh? It doesn't display any data because you've never told it to. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i just want to read the environment varibles which are passed from the proxy..

Comment: Could you give us some more information about your setup and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to get the source ip for every HTTP request and based on that the script redirects users to certain sites..i have used sys.stdin.readlines() but it does not throw the source ip but i get all the other fields, however the env variable in bash shows all the HTTP headers including client IP...

Comment: What's serving your HTTP requests? Are you using a [python http server](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html)?

Comment: no its a proxy program called safesquid..and it supports extranal parser similar to redirect program in squid..

Comment: Are you set on using python not PHP? http://www.safesquid.com/html/portal.php?page=44

Comment: Your question still makes no sense. *What, directly, are you trying to achieve?*

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I think he's writing an external parser for safesquid. He first used his bash script above, and his `env` call would get all the "environmental variables" such as Client IP. Now he's trying to write a python program instead, but `os.environ` only gets the local environmental variables, not from the HTTP request. I think safesquid is sending this data via stdin to the program, as per [this page](http://www.safesquid.com/html/portal.php?page=39) ie `Pipe: Content is piped to the program's STDIN`

Comment: See his other question: http://serverfault.com/questions/355083/safesquid-external-parser

Comment: so why is the STDIN input from commandline different than STDIN from HTTP request, and in bash it works whereas in python it doesn't work with os.environ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're after the same output as a unix `env` command, could you call it directly?

```
log = subprocess.check_output("env")
```

Comment: no it does not log when traffic comes from the proxy to the script.. works OK if i pass STDIN data from the commandline